# Users aren't redirected to the front page after account cancellation

Tags: users

I have a problem with account cancellation. The proccess itself executes fine, but after the batch proccess runs, the user isn't redirected to the front page as mentioned in the `UserController::confirmCancel` method:

```
user_cancel($edit, $user->id(), $account_data['cancel_method']);
// Since user_cancel() is not invoked via Form API, batch processing
// needs to be invoked manually and should redirect to the front page
// after completion.
return batch_process('');
```

This results in 403 error, as anonymous users don't have access to `en/user/2/cancel/confirm/...` path. I tested in in 2 different sites, using Drupal 8.2 and 8.3

How can I redirect user properly in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using custom service. Will post it here shortly.